# Regular expression for a string with multiple conditions

Tags: r, regex

I have got an expression – **]006IRBTS1[ g600 niT erauqS ehcoirB g004** g001 /p 57.01$ hcnuB /p 51.2$

I want to extract the portion in bold. The logic is:

1. Start with “]“.
2. Take everything until you get to “[“ including “[“.
3. Include the next 10 characters/digits whatever it is.
4. After those 10 characters/digits, include all letters and white spaces

until you hit a digit. Capture the digit and everything that follows until you hit a whitespace.

I am using the following regular expression in R. It doesn’t work of course. Any thoughts?

```
"^].+\\[.{10}[A-Za-z\\s]+[0-9\\.]+\\s"
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/TpoV52/1 ?

Answer (score 3):

1) Start with “]“.

```
\]
```

2) Take everything until you get to “[“ including “[“.

```
[^\[]+\[
```

3) Include the next 10 characters/digits whatever it is.

```
.{,10}
```

4) After those 10 characters/digits, include all letters and white spaces until you hit a digit.

```
[a-zA-Z\s]+\d
```

5) Capture the digit and everything that follows until you hit a whitespace.

```
[^\s]+
```

Combined:

```
\][^\[]+\[.{,10}[a-zA-Z\s]+\d[^\s]+
```

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/TpoV52/1

**UPDATE**

I changed the very last quantifier from + to * so it can match *some* or *none* more characters.

That is because given "Capture the digit and everything that follows until you hit a whitespace" it is possible that after that digit immediately a whitespace follows. This is the case in the 2nd subject string you gave in your comment:

```
]006IRBTS1[ g600 niT erauqS ehcoirB g4 g001 /p 57.01$ hcnuB /p 51.2$
```

The updated pattern, below, will stop at the "capture that digit" (g**4**) because "and everything that follows until you hit a whitespace" is actually nothing. (Whitespace is next char after digit.)

```
\][^\[]+\[.{,10}[a-zA-Z\s]+\d[^\s]*
```

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/TpoV52/2

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. One issue is that if I change the expression to "]006IRBTS1[ g600 niT erauqS ehcoirB g4 g001 /p 57.01$ hcnuB /p 51.2$", it doesn't work. In the highlighted portion at the end of the string, I edited g004 to g4.

Comment: This is what I have got for all my use cases. "\\][^\\[]+\\[.{,10}[a-zA-Z\\s]+[\\d\\.]+" works in Python. In R, I am using "\\][^\\[]+\\[.{,10}[a-zA-Z\\s]+[\\d\\.]+". It does not work. I have added the double slash for escaping characters. Why is it not working in R?

Comment: FYI "The perl = TRUE argument to grep, regexpr, gregexpr, sub, gsub and strsplit switches to the PCRE library that implements regular expression pattern matching using the same syntax and semantics as Perl 5.x, with just a few differences." https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html

Comment: Thanks mate. This issue was driving me insane. It is working now.

Comment: Why `{,10}` (zero to ten) instead of `{10}` (exactly ten)?

Comment: @TimPietzker, that is correct and you can see that in the second regex101 example it was already changed.